# Multi-platform WCF service settings

Tags: android, asp.net, json, wcf, web-services

I'm making a WCF service that will be consumed on android and possibly in the future on the iPad,  i Just need advice on selecting development options that will make life easier in the future!

the Service itself

1. Authenticates
2. Receives a list a class
3. streams a file download to the client(android) on request of the client

There are **so many options I'm asking which would be best for this project ? (as mentioned above)**

format ?  **Rest/soap/json/odata/**

also which method of binding should i use for a file stream transfer(as opposed to fully buffered downloads)

Binding ? **basicHttp/WsHttp/NetTcpBinding/NetNamedPipeBinding**

any advice/examples of authenticating or streaming a download with a wcf and android  would be welcome

also which security methods would suit this project ?

Thanks for any advice, I'm new to services

Comment: Have you looked at any of the numerous articles on WCF - either on MSDN or developer's blogs?  It sounds like your relatively new to WCF, and it would be to your benefit to spend some time researching the basics.  Your question as is could be deemed too vague and get closed.